# Find the least sigma-field $\mathcal{F}$ such that $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $A,B \subset X$ and let $A \not= \emptyset$ and $B \not= \emptyset$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Find the least sigma-field $\mathcal{F}$ such that $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$.What will change when $A \cap B \not= \emptyset$ ?

My attempt:

I think that $\mathcal{F} = \left\{\emptyset,X,A,B,X \setminus A, X \setminus B , A \cup B, X \setminus (A \cup B) \right\} $

What will change when $A \cap B \not= \emptyset$ ?

I think that

$\mathcal{F} = \left\{\emptyset,X,A,B,X \setminus A, X \setminus B , A \cup B, X \setminus (A \cup B), A \cap B, X \setminus (A \cap B) \right\} $

Am I right? I will grateful for check.

Comment: ..in the case that $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$, what about sets like $B \backslash A$ and $A \backslash B$?

Comment: .. the second one couldn't be complete ... a finite $\sigma$-algebra has always $2^k$ elements for some $k$ ...

Comment: Ok so in the second case: $\left\{\emptyset,X,A,B,X \setminus A, X \setminus B , A \cup B, X \setminus (A \cup B), A \setminus B , B \setminus A , A \cap B, X \setminus (A \cap B) , (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \right\} \subset \mathcal{F} $ 





so I need three sets more yet? How find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with something like this, I sometimes resort to this process to ensure that I have accounted for all the possibilities:

Draw a Venn diagram, and label the individual areas 1, 2, 3 and 4. Then list the possibilities.

[image: simple venn diagram]

So I use 234 as an abbreviation for $A\cup B$, etc.

Now the 16 sets you need are all possible combinations: $1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, \dots 234, 1234$ together with the empty set.

Listing the sets you require in a table, you get:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
~ & ~ & \emptyset & ~ & X & ~ & 1234 \\
23 & ~ & A & ~ & X\setminus A & ~ & 14 \\
34 & ~ & B & ~ & X\setminus B & ~ & 12 \\
3 & ~ & A\cap B & ~ & X\setminus (A\cap B) & ~ & 124 \\
234 & ~ & A\cup B & ~ & X\setminus (A\cup B) & ~ & 1 \\
2 & ~ & A \setminus B & ~ & X\setminus (A \setminus B) & ~ & 134 \\
4 & ~ & B \setminus A & ~ & X\setminus (B \setminus A) & ~ & 123 \\
24 & ~ & A \Delta B & ~ & X\setminus (A \Delta B) & ~ & 13 \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference $(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$.

You should be able to work out which ones you have missed from here.